# Code::Blocks automatically adds the flag -Wall to the compilation

Tags: c++

Code::Blocks automatically adds the flag -Wall to the compilation

It is turned off in the settings, but it still adds it.

How to remove?

Comment: Probably didn't turn it off properly. Check both the global IDE settings and the project settings. In both, check both "debug", "release", and the "entire project" settings (the tree on the left switches between the three).

Comment: I wonder why one would want to compile code with `-Wall` turned off.

Comment: As a counterpoint to turning off `-Wall`, I suggest instead you compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and fix all issues.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Unfortunately, it's quite a common thing in people who are told they need their code to compile without warnings (or who's performance is measured by minimising number of warnings).   I've seen it in both academic/teaching settings and professional settings, with developers who seek ways to stop the compiler giving warnings/errors instead of fixing code.  I understand that such a mindset is actually the historical reason that most modern compilers default to DISABLING a lot of warnings (developers with that mindset lobbied vendors to disable warnings by default).

Comment: @Peter that's a pretty silly approach to "fix", but yeah 

Comment: @RichardCritten frankly this should be the accepted answer since it won’t be long before he is back asking why the code “compiles fine” but doesn’t work.

Comment: @Taekahn why? everything works without these flags when compiled manually

Comment: @AleksandrSteblevets why not post some of the warnings, we might be able to tell you :- if they are safe to ignore, extensions to the C++ Standard, or Undefined  Behaviour.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have been programming for 4 years. Decided to try C++ for the first time. I know some warnings are dangerous to ignore, but I really need to turn off the warnings

Comment: @AleksandrSteblevets because, just because a c++ program compiles, executes, and does what’s expected does not mean you have a well formed c++ program. You say “everything works” but if you’re ignoring warnings a more appropriate phrase is probably “everything is currently working” but that could change at any moment without any changes to your source code. Or it could change with seemingly unrelated changes to your source code. I’ve seen firsthand adding an extra line of code to a TU causing ignored UB that previous worked to exhibit a mystery bug.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   I agree.   It's a sad reflection of the mindset of too many software developers.